# How do you configure dns to allow for a url a domain to be pointed to another url?

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, webserver, cname, amazon-route53

I'm interested in setting up mysite.com's blog with a url on the domain:

```
Desired: mysite.com/blog
Not blog.mysite.com
```

Example: http://37signals.com/svn/

How do you go about modifying the DNS to make this happen? I'm not sure what this is called which is making it hard to even google search for ideas.

Thank you

Comment: Are you saying you have a server with the domain mysite.com, and you want to install a blog on mysite.com/blog?

Comment: I don't want to install a blog, I want to set it up so mysite.com/blog points to a tumblr or some other blogging platform. just like 37signals

Comment: http://37signals.com/svn/ and http://37signals.com/ are both on the same server.

Comment: Anyway, DNS basically resolves everything to the left of the first '/' in the url - you can point different subdomains to different IP address, but a subfolder won't trigger DNS resolution.  You would have to bounce all the requests through your main server to the alternate location.

Answer (score 0):

What @SamDufel says is right: a domain is one thing (a name for an IP address), a path is something on a server.

This mapping starts at the domain registrar (e.g. GoDaddy), where the DNS service for the domain is defined.  If yours is defined to point to AWS Route 53 servers, then that's where you make DNS changes.  Until you change the DNS settings at your domain registrar, then tend to use their own DNS servers.

So now you need to make sure your domain `mysite.com` resolves to the server hosting your blog.  If you're using tumblr, you would probably need to create a CNAME record in your DNS configuration.  But this still just results in an IP address (saying, "whatever IP address I get from tumblr.com I'll get from mysite.com").

So it's very likely that you would need to configure the tumblr account to know what to do when it gets requests from that domain -- it's entirely up to the blog software how this is handled.